# Chromecast and HDMI-CEC in Android

Tags: android, google-cast, hdmi

As I can see, Chromecast supports HDMI-CEC to control TV, for example - switch TV input. But I did not found in the documentation how it can be implemented. Is SDK for Android support TV control through HDMI-CEC? And if so - what methods and classes I must use to control it?

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec for chromecast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If HDMI-CEC is supported on your TV, you don't need to do anything extra from your android application; when user connects to your cast device, TV will be automatically turned on and input source will switch appropriately. On your receiver, there are a couple of things that you can do if you wish, and if the HDMI stack supports it: for example if you are casting a video to your chromecast device and user grabs the remote control and switches the input away from your chromecast input, you will receive a webkitvisibilitychange event in your receiver app so you can, say, pause the video.

Comment: It's interesting and useful, but I want to know - is it possible to control TV via SDK?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: @AliNaddaf gave you a +1 for being right (I assume, given what you said in your profile about what you do for a living :-]), but that's not at all what most people care about.  I think the original poster was asking for something like https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec for chromecast, not just consumer-level stuff like you talked about.

Comment: User was asking if Chromecast SDK for Android can control TV through CEC and the answer I gave was targeted to that question.

Comment: @AliNaddaf, does your answer need an update now that new chromecast firmware seems to better support HDMI-CEC?

Comment: Answer to the original question remains the same in the sense that there is no API exposed for you in the SDK to control the CEC; the support in the framework has been expanded but no exposure through the APIs.

Comment: Can this same thing be said of ChromeCast Senders written using the Chrome API (not Android)?